# Finding the value of $x$ within summation

Tags: summation

I have two equations that I have to find the value of two variables within them. It also uses summation in both equation. My purpose is finding the value of $x$ and $y$. Can you help me with how to modify the equation to be like $(x = \ldots, y = \ldots)$ The complete equations are stated below:
$$\sum_{k=c_i}^H (H-c_i)_{k}x^{k-c_i} y = Q_i(H)$$
and
$$\sum_{k=c_i}^H (k-c_i)(H-c_i)_{k}x^{k-c_i} y= L_i(H)$$

where $(n)_k=n(n−1)...(n−k+1)$

Comment: Almost trivially you can write $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} Q_{i}(H) = L_{i}(H)$$ - what does $(\cdots)_k$ mean in this context?

Comment: I forgot to mention that 
$(n)_k=n(n-1) ... (n-k+1)$